# HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: angular, ionic2

When making the GET method Service call using Postman, I get a successful response, but when doing the same call from Angular, I get the 405 error.

```
var token = "sdfasdfasdfasdfaerqwelruaoeuapiou"
this.contentHeader = new Headers({"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer"+token});

  this.http = http;
  this.url=IES.serviceUrl+'page/'+this.pageName;
  this.http.get(this.url,{ headers: this.contentHeader }).map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.pageData = data;
    this.pageControls = this.pageData.controls;
  } , error => {
        console.log('failed');
  });
```

This code sends the required "Authorization" header when run in IE browser, but fails to send the headers in FF/chrome

The fiddler capture for FF/Chrome Browser is:

```
Request-Headers
...................
OPTIONS localurl HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:21326
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:8100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8100/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8


response(during angular call)
............
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: GET
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpc2FyZA==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Date: Thu, 23 Feb 2017 04:12:19 GMT
Content-Length: 76

{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'."}
```

The same for Rest Client in firefox or from IE Browser  is similar to

```
Request
.....................

GET localurl HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:21326
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: null
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer 9myBifb-HJG9tVpyopK495BA....String Truncated
Connection: keep-alive


Response
......................
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpc2FyZA==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Date: Thu, 23 Feb 2017 04:14:09 GMT
Content-Length: 221

{"PageId":1,"PageName":"dashboard","controls":["barchart","pieChart","scatterChart"],"lists":{},"actions":{}}
```

Notice the Authorization Header in this

Comment: Sounds like a CORS preflight

Comment: How to solve that

Comment: Problem is in the CORS in the api service its not because of angular 2 and ionic 2 ??

Comment: You need to configure CORS support on the server side

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Provide all the relevant information. That way people can give an accurate solution

Comment: To enable CORS on WebApi, use the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package. click here for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: But it is working in IE(internet Explorer) but not in chrome

Comment: In webApi we have added <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS"/>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization"/>

Comment: But it is working in IE(internet Explorer) but not in chrome

Comment: @peeskillet the server has required headers